# Работа с клиентскими каталогами/файлами

Tags: веб-программирование, flash

Есть сайт-киоск.
Необходимо сделать, чтобы в этом киоске можно было показать локальные картинки.
Ситуация: Человек воткнул флешку в киоск, на сайте появилась галерея.

По факту мне необходимо показать каталоги из этой флешки - аля фотоальбомы.
Затем получить ссылки на локальные файлы (file:///path/to/file.jpg) либо base64 представление.

Порыл инет и встретил несколько раз что это невозможно из за security reasons.
Что скажете, как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это сделать невозможно, flash не дает прямого доступа к ф.с., только через FileReference (через FileReference доступ к отдельному файлу).

Comment: Всмысле через FileReference возможно?

Answer (score 0):

Если сайт развернут внутри киоска (в пределах одной ОС), то получайте доступ к флешке со стороны серверной части сайта.

Если сайт развернут на удаленном (относительно киоска) сервере и инфраструктура вам доступна для доработки можно настроить на киоске автомонтирование и предоставлять доступ серверу к флешке через отдельное соединение (nfs, sshfs...)

Comment: Решили на киоск установить node.js и сделать сервис, который будет отдавать нужный список папок и файлов к примеру json-ом

Comment: @Skywave Тоже вариант. Не забудьте шифровать соединение и настроить авторизацию